# Can I turn specific weapon on auto fire without forcing all of my weapons to do so?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If I have 3 weapons on my ship, lets say an Artemis Missile, an Ion Blast, and a Pike Beam, can I have my Ion Blast on auto-fire at their shields, and then use the beam and missiles without them picking up the auto-fire command as well?

I'm aware I can manually shoot once and then turn off the next shot, but I'm looking for an alternative as sometimes I get distracted and forget, ensuingly wasting a volley oppourtunity.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As FTL itself mentions, if you hover over the 'AUTOFIRE' button:

You can use LCtrl+Aim to force the opposite of the current autofire setting, i.e. hold LCtrl while you aim each weapon you intend to autofire, which will then autofire while the *overall* autofire control is turned *off*.

Comment: Thanks! I had read that tooltip but couldnt figure out how it worked